# Override Magento Controller_Abstract

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, magento-1.7

We have modified Magento's history.phtml to show all orders, without any limitation for a restricted website. This is working, but we ran into a problem when we are trying to print or view an order. I've debugged and the problem lays with Magento's `_canViewOrder` (located in `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract`). In that function, an extra and ofcourse logical check is implemented to check if the user that is logged in can view/print the order that is requested:

```
if ($order->getId() && $order->getCustomerId() && ($order->getCustomerId() == $customerId)
            && in_array($order->getState(), $availableStates, $strict = true)
```

As we have some custom development here, we need to **override this method** to remove the restriction. Unfortunately We can't find anywhere how to override a **Controller** class.

*Please note we do know how to override routers/controllers, but this one is located in the Controller folder and is an abstract class.*

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide me with a sample config.xml to override this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've decided to use the quick way after all. I've overridden the `Mage_Sales_OrderController`:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Sales') . DS . 'OrderController.php';
class MyCompany_MyModule_OrderController extends Mage_Sales_OrderController
{   
    /**
     * Check order view availability
     * Overridden from Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract to
     * remove the customer restriction. We want to show all
     * orders to all customers on any time. 
     * 
     * TODO: Maybe in the future add a customer group restriction
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
     * @return  bool
     */
    protected function _canViewOrder($order)
    {
        $availableStates = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates();
        if ($order->getId() && in_array($order->getState(), $availableStates, $strict = true)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

In my **config.xml** I'm telling Magento to use my controller first and use the `OrderController` as back-up. As I've only overridden one function, all the existing code will not be touched.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
...

<frontend>
...
    <routers>
...
        <sales>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyCompany_MyModule before="Mage_Sales_OrderController">MyCompany_MyModule_Sales</MyCompany_MyModule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </sales>
    </routers>
...
</frontend>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override any class by placing it in `app/code/local`. When loading a class, Magento looks first in local, then community, then core. To achieve what you want, copy the file to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Controller/Abstract.php` and make your amendments.

However, try and avoid this approach where possible as it can make things a little messy when it comes to upgrades. One option you might want to consider is modifying the controller that is extending `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract`, and overriding the `_canViewOrder` method of it. See here: http://drupal.org/project/magento

Comment: First of all: thanks for your comment. I know I can override entire files like that, but I prefer not to do so. We always override a file in the sense of extending. Like that we only have to override one method or most of the time we can just use the parent and than do some stuff after it. I'm trying to override the controller underneath as we speak, but that is worst-case IMO.